# Preventing Remote Desktop Use for Active Directory Users

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop

Is it possible to restrict the applications that an active directory user can have access to? Specifically is there a way where I can prevent them from using Remote Desktop?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Do you want to restrict the use of using RDP or restrict what they can connect to? Unless it is specifically setup, you can't RDP into a server or a workstation by default.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to restrict all access of Remote Desktop for developers as a security measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this goal would be through the use of [AppLocker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994629.aspx).

An excerpt from the link above:

> AppLocker helps administrators control how users can access and use files, such as executable files, packaged apps, scripts, Windows Installer files, and DLLs. Using AppLocker, you can:
>
> - ...
> - Create exceptions to rules. For example, you can create a rule that allows all Windows processes to run except Registry Editor (Regedit.exe).

That example in particular sounds like it fits the bill, except you would replace Regedit.exe with mstsc.exe.

You use Group Policy to configure AppLocker for computers in an AD domain.

[image: AppLocker]